# PHP - Validar POST para traer información de la base de datos no funciona

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al momento de cargar una página con una query a mi base de datos. Tengo validado que se ejecute el código validando la acción del botón del formulario así:

```
if (isset(_POST['btnBuscarAhora'])) {

  echo "Entro";
.... 
....
```

Pero por alguna razón, ingreso (me valido en el index.php y me manda al buscador.php) y al completar los campos del formulario no entra al `if` para ejecutar el código SQL y no trae nada de la DB. Validé el `_POST` y éste si trae la información del formulario:

```
Array ( [stringBusqueda] => DOCUMENTO [stringUsuario] => CA9120 [submit] => btnBuscarAhora )
```

Lo que me llama la atención es que si coloco:

```
if (!isset(_POST['btnBuscarAhora'])) {
.... 
....
```

Refresco la página, me trae la información y me puedo mover dentro del paginador sin problemas. ¿Qué es lo que tengo mal al momento de validar?. El código completo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mb-5"></h1>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item my-5">

<form method="POST">
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input required name="stringBusqueda" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" inputString" placeholder="Ingrese palabra clave">  
      <input required name="stringUsuario" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Ingrese usuario">  
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="btnBuscarAhora">Buscar Ahora</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</li>

</ul>

<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'conexion.php';
session_start();
print_r($_POST);

 if (isset($_POST['stringBusqueda'])) {
    $_SESSION['stringBusqueda'] = $_POST['stringBusqueda'];
  }

  if (isset($_POST['stringUsuario'])) {
    $_SESSION['stringUsuario'] = $_POST['stringUsuario'];
  }

if (isset(_POST['btnBuscarAhora'])) { ##Valido TRUE del form con el btnBuscarAhora

  echo "Entro";


  $sql = ("SELECT path,name,storage,user_id FROM oc_filecache INNER JOIN oc_mounts ON storage=storage_id  WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['stringBusqueda'] . "%' AND `user_id`  LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['stringUsuario'] . "%' ");
  #echo "SQL1: $sql";

  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $totalRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  $registrosPorPag = 4;
  $paginasTotal = ceil($totalRegistros/$registrosPorPag);
  $row_count=0;


    $inicio = ($_GET['pagina'] - 1) * $registrosPorPag;

    $sql = ("SELECT path,name,storage,user_id FROM oc_filecache INNER JOIN oc_mounts ON storage=storage_id WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['stringBusqueda'] . "%' AND `user_id`  LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['stringUsuario'] . "%' LIMIT $inicio , $registrosPorPag");
    #echo "SQL2: $sql";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    ?>

    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']<=1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
          <a class="page-link" href="buscador.php?pagina=<?php echo  $_GET['pagina']-1 ?>">Anterior
          </a>
        </li>
        <?php for($i=0; $i<$paginasTotal ; $i++) : ?>
          <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']==$i+1 ? 'active' : '' ?>">
            <a class="page-link" href="buscador.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1 ?>">
          <?php echo $i+1 ?></a>
          </li>
        <?php endfor ?>
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']>=$paginasTotal ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
          <a class="page-link" href="buscador.php?pagina=<?php echo  $_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">Siguiente
          </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  <?php      
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ##cierra n2
        $row_count=0

    ?>
    <table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
     <tr>
        <th width='5%'>Count</th>
        <th width='10%'>Usuario</th>
        <th>Archivo encontrado</th>
<!--         <th>Ruta de archivo</th> -->
        <th align="center">Acceso Ruta</th>
      </tr> 
    <?php
        while($dato = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ##cierra n1
            $row_count++;      
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_count ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dato['user_id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dato['name'] ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php
        } ##cierra n1
      } ##cierra n2
    else { ?> 
      <tr>
          <td  align="center"><strong>No hay registros</strong></td>
      </tr> 
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php 
mysqli_close($db);
?>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

Gracias por la aclaración. Lo que me sucede es que al validar de a forma:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Por alguna razón el al moverme dentro del nº de pág (Ej, de la pagina nº a la nº2), pierdo la data y el array me vuelve vacío

```
Array ( )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si tienes más información, edita tu pregunta en vez de crear una respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando mandas un formulario, los datos de éste se serializan en un array que se podrá recuperar por `$_POST` o por `$_GET` según el caso.

Ese array tendrá pares clave/valor, donde la clave es lo que haya en el atributo `name` del formulario y en valor lo que haya en el atributo `value` de los `input`.

Lo que hace `isset()` es **verificar si la clave que indiques existe en el array**. Es decir que al hacer esto:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnBuscarAhora'])) {
```

Lo que preguntas literalmente es si `$_POST` tiene una clave llamada `btnBuscarAhora`. Y no, no la tiene, si vemos tu array:

```
Array ( 
            [stringBusqueda] => DOCUMENTO 
            [stringUsuario] => CA9120 
            [submit] => btnBuscarAhora 
      )
```

Las claves son los valores de la izquierda (las que se usarán con `isset`, la clave para el dato que buscas es `submit` y `btnBuscarAhora` es el valor.

Entonces, la forma de preguntar sería:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

O, si quieres verificar en un contexto donde pueden haber varias acciones, tendrías que recuperar el valor y preguntar por él, algo así:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='btnBuscarAhora') {
```

O bien cambiar la lógica, cambiando el `name` del `input`, en vez de `submit`, dándole el atributo `btnBuscarAhora`.

O, como bien indica @Jakala en su comentario puedes implementar una técnica mucho más limpia que consiste en recuperar el valor en una variable y luego usar esa variable en lo adelante.

Aquí usaré un operador ternario para verificar si el POST tiene ese dato, guardándolo en una variable:

```
$mSubmit=!( empty($_POST['submit']) ) ? $_POST['submit'] : NULL;
```

Aquí, si el POST no tiene nada en `submit` o la clave no existe, el valor de `$mSubmit` será `NULL`, de lo contrario, tendrá el valor asociado a esa clave.

Luego, si necesitas usar ese valor, usas `$mSubmit`, por ejemplo:

```
if ($mSubmit==="btnBuscarAhora") {
    //...
}
```

Comment: En este caso creo que lo mejor sería con `!empty($_POST...)` ya que será obligatorio que esté definido y tenga un valor

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un buscador, lo mejor es usar el método GET, porque te permite agregar a favoritos y, lo principal, paginar fácilmente.

```
<form method="GET">
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input required name="stringBusqueda" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" inputString" placeholder="Ingrese palabra clave">  
      <input required name="stringUsuario" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Ingrese usuario">  
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="btnBuscarAhora">Buscar Ahora</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Luego, no puedes tener `session_start()` después de una salida HTML, en todo caso, coloca esa línea antes de incluir `header.php`; en todo caso, como no estás usando las variables de sesión, las omití en esta respuesta.

> Quito la parte de asignación ternaria, creo que no se necesita

Procesando el formulario (o la URL): Es necesario crear variables de cada cosa involucrada para poder usarlas en todo el proceso y, de paso, evitar errores. Entonces, las variables a crear: stringBusqueda, stringUsuario y pagina:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'conexion.php';

// Obtener cadenas de búsqueda o dejar en blanco si no existen
$stringBusqueda = (isset($_GET['stringBusqueda'])) ? $_GET['stringBusqueda'] : '';
$stringUsuario = (isset($_GET['stringUsuario'])) ? $_GET['stringUsuario'] : '';

// Obtener número de página o inicializar en 1
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
```

Ya teniendo todo listo, es momento de ver si es necesario realizar consulta o no; el resto de comentarios acerca de la consulta va dentro del código:

```
// Validar que hay algo para buscar, no necesitamos el botón
// solo que alguna de las dos cadenas (o ambas) tenga contenido
if($stringBusqueda != '' || $stringUsuario != '') { // Primer if
    // Crear filtro
    $filtro = ' WHERE ';
    // Agregar nombre solo si no está en blanco
    if($stringBusqueda != '') {
        $filtro .= "`name` LIKE '%$stringBusqueda%'";
    }
    // Agregar user_id solo si no está en blanco
    if($stringUsuario != '') {
        // Si la búsqueda por nombre no está en blanco, se necesita AND
        $filtro .= ($stringBusqueda != '') ? ' AND ' : '';
        $filtro .= "`user_id` LIKE '%$stringUsuario%'";
    }
    // Contar resultados, es mejor con COUNT(*)
    $cuenta = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oc_filecache' . $filtro;
    // Devuelve solo una fila y una columna
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    // Leer fila con array numérico
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    // Obtener total de registros
    $totalRegistros = $fila[0];

    $registrosPorPag = 4;
    $paginasTotal = ceil($totalRegistros/$registrosPorPag);
    $row_count=0;


    $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $registrosPorPag;

    // Crear consulta con filtro y solo elementos de página actual
    $sql = "SELECT path,name,storage,user_id FROM oc_filecache INNER JOIN oc_mounts ON storage=storage_id $filteo LIMIT $inicio , $registrosPorPag";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

Para poder paginar, necesitas agregar cada elemento al enlace, de forma que todos estén incluidos en $_GET para la siguiente petición:

```
    $link = 'buscador.php?stringBusqueda=' . urlencode($stringBusqueda) . '&stringUsuario=' . urlencode($stringusuario);
?>

    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $pagina == 1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
          <a class="page-link" href="<?php echo $link; ?>&pagina=<?php echo  $pagina - 1 ?>">Anterior</a>
        </li>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=$paginasTotal ; $i++) : ?>
          <li class="page-item <?php echo $pagina == $i ? 'active' : '' ?>">
            <a class="page-link" href="<?php echo $link; ?>&pagina=<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></a>
          </li>
        <?php endfor ?>
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $pagina == $paginasTotal ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
          <a class="page-link" href="<?php echo $link; ?>&pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">Siguiente</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  <?php      
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ##cierra n2
        $row_count=0

    ?>
    <table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
     <tr>
        <th width='5%'>Count</th>
        <th width='10%'>Usuario</th>
        <th>Archivo encontrado</th>
<!--         <th>Ruta de archivo</th> -->
        <th align="center">Acceso Ruta</th>
      </tr> 
    <?php
        while($dato = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ##cierra n1
            $row_count++;      
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_count ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dato['user_id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dato['name'] ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php
        } ##cierra n1
      } ##cierra n2
    else { ?> 
      <tr>
          <td  align="center"><strong>No hay registros</strong></td>
      </tr> 
      <?php } // Cierra else n2?>
</table>
    <?php } // Cierra primer if ?>

<?php 
mysqli_close($db);
?>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Triby, Gracias por la ayuda lo pude corregir con lo que me explicaste.